# FFMPEG - how to identify a bottleneck in hardware transcoding?

Tags: ffmpeg, nvidia, hardware, video-processing, hardware-acceleration

In the provided example I was trying to transcode a 4K h264 source to a 1080p h264 output using Nvidia's Hardware acceleration.

Relevant information:

```
ffmpeg version git-2017-12-25-613f789 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-amf --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libmfx
  libavutil      56.  7.100 / 56.  7.100
  libavcodec     58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
  libavformat    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavdevice    58.  0.100 / 58.  0.100
  libavfilter     7.  7.100 /  7.  7.100
  libswscale      5.  0.101 /  5.  0.101
  libswresample   3.  0.101 /  3.  0.101
  libpostproc    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
```

Command used:

```
ffmpeg -c:v h264_cuvid -i "4K_input.mp4" -c:v h264_nvenc -preset slow -s 1920x1080 -c:a copy output.mkv
```

Relevant PC Specs:

```
GPU: (Gigabyte) GeForce GTX 1070 Ti
CPU: Intel Core i7 7700K
Memory: 8GB DDR4 2400MHz Single Channel.
SSD: Crucial CT525MX3
```

While the Nvidia Desktop recording has absolutely no issues to record live h264 video in up to 50Mbps bitrates, this encoding at below 2600kbps was extremely slow utilizing barely 35% GPU.
I was unable to utilize 100% of the GPU on any video parameters.

This is why I could use some advice concerning how to identify a (suspected) bottleneck.

Answer (score 4):

"GPU" transcoding does not work that way. There are fixed function circuits dedicated to h264 encoding on Nvidia GPUs that are not part of the vector unit pool. This is why you specify `h264_nvenc` (nvenc is Nvidia specific) and not a generic `gpu` encoder.

TLDR, you won't reach 100% GPU because its not really using the GPU. Its using a separate component that comes with your GPU.

[image]

Comment: This is pretty much what the FFMPEG manual about hardware encoding (found https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro) specified as "Full hardware transcode with CUVID and NVENC".
Should I try using a different hardware accelerated solution supported by my GPU instead ? (if it is not a bottleneck that is.)

Comment: I've added the image to visualize your answer - feel free to roll back. It's possible to reach 100% by encode multiple videos simultaniously